# Not able to access functions from object

Tags: c++

I am working on a project which I have to include a header file to my main.cpp. The header file is a heap which is using a template file. For reasons that escape me the insert and remove functions cannot be "seen" in the main file. I am getting an error message: C:/Users/Tito/Documents/C++proj/cs3304/Homework2_2/Homework10/main.cpp:58:17: error: request for member 'remove' in 'enter1', which is of non-class type 'priority_queue_heap()'. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? I will really appreciate it.

Thanks

Here are the lines of code:

Main.cpp:

```
/**
* Insert a few elements into a heap and the remove them
* one by one and see if we get them in the right.
*/

 #include "priority_queue_heap.h"
 #include "heap.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ctime>
 using namespace std;

 int test1() {
heap<int> hp;
hp.insert(1);
hp.insert(2);
hp.insert(3);
hp.insert(4);
hp.insert(5);
hp.check_heap();

int x = hp.remove();
cout << "removed " << x << endl;
x = hp.remove();
cout << "removed " << x << endl;
x = hp.remove();
cout << "removed " << x << endl;
x = hp.remove();
cout << "removed " << x << endl;
x = hp.remove();
cout << "removed " << x << endl;

cout << "empty? " << hp.is_empty() << endl;
 }

void test2() {
srand(time(NULL));
heap<int> hp;
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++ ) {
    hp.insert(rand());
}
while(!hp.is_empty()) {
    int x = hp.remove();
    cout << x << endl;
}

 }

 int main() {
/*test1();
test2();*/
priority_queue_heap<int> enter1();
enter1.insert(135);
enter1.insert(909);
enter1.insert(203);

cout<<endl;
cout<< "values to be removed" << endl;
cout << enter1.remove() << endl;


 }
```

heap.h:

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H

/**
* This class implements a heap as described in the text.
* We will treat it as a priority queue.
*/

template <class T>
class heap {
public:
static const int CAPACITY = 10;

heap() {
    size = 0;
}

bool is_empty() const { return  size == 0;}
bool is_full() const { return size == CAPACITY; }

/**
 * Remove the largest value from this heap and return it.
 *
 * Precondition: heap is not empty.
 */
T remove();

/**
 * Inserts the 'value' into the heap.
 *
 * Precondition: heap is not full
 */
void insert(const T& value);


/**
 * Check if the heap is valid.
 * Prints out each parent and its children (for all nodes with children)
 * Stops when a parent is less than one or both of its children
 * Prints 'check' for each parent that is greater than or equal to its
   children
 */
  bool check_heap();

private:
T data[CAPACITY];
int size;
};

#include "heap.template"


#endif // HEAP_H
```

heap.template:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

/*
 *   parent index is p, children are at indices 2*p+1 and 2*p+2
 *      You must check that those are in range
 *
 *   child index is c, parent index is (c-1)/2  (integer division)
 */


/**
* Inserts the 'value' into the heap.
*
* Precondition: heap is not full
*/
template <class T>
void heap<T>::insert(const T& value) {
assert(!is_full());

//std::cout << size << std::endl;

// add the value to a new node in proper position
data[size] = value;
size++;

// move the value up the tree as needed
int child = size-1;  // index of the new 'node'
int parent = (child-1)/2;  // index of the parent

while((child > 0) && (data[parent] < data[child])) {
    // swap parent and child values
    T tmp = data[parent];
    data[parent] = data[child];
    data[child] = tmp;
    // update parent and child
    child = parent; // this is where new value is!
    parent = (child-1)/2;
}

// it's a heap!

}

/**
 * Remove the largest value from this heap and return it.
 *
 * Precondition: heap is not empty.
 */
template <class T>
T heap<T>::remove() {
assert(!is_empty());

//  grab first element, save it for return later
T save = data[0];

// copy last value in list to the beginning
// decrement size
data[0] = data[size-1];
size--;

//    size--;
//    data[0] = data[size];

// sift the new first element down until it finds its place
int parent = 0;
int left_child = 2*parent+1;
int right_child = 2*parent+2;
bool still_working = true;

while(still_working && left_child < size) {  // while the parent has at
least one child
    if(right_child >= size) {
        // only the left child to worry about
        if(data[parent] < data[left_child]) {
            // out of order, so swap them
            T t = data[parent];
            data[parent] = data[left_child];
            data[left_child] = t;
            parent = left_child;
            still_working = false;  // we must be done!
        } else {
            still_working = false;
        }
    } else {
        // two children
        if(data[left_child] > data[right_child]) {
            //left child larger
            if(data[parent] < data[left_child]) {
                // out of order, so swap them
                T t = data[parent];
                data[parent] = data[left_child];
                data[left_child] = t;
                parent = left_child;
            } else {
                still_working = false;
            }
        } else {
            // right child larger
            if(data[parent] < data[right_child]) {
                // out of order, so swap them
                T t = data[parent];
                data[parent] = data[right_child];
                data[right_child] = t;
                parent = right_child;
            } else {
                still_working = false;
            }
        }
        left_child = 2*parent + 1;
        right_child = 2*parent + 2;
    }
}

return save;
}

/**
* Check if the heap is valid.
* Prints out each parent and its children (for all nodes with children)
* Stops when a parent is less than one or both of its children
* Prints 'check' for each parent that is greater than or equal to its
children
*/
template <class T>
bool heap<T>::check_heap() {
for(int p = 0; p < size; p++ ) {
    int cl = 2*p+1;
    int cr = 2*p+2;
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << p  << std::setw(10) << data[p];
    if(cl < size) {  // p has a left child?
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << data[cl];
        if(data[p] < data[cl]) {
            std:exit(1);
        }
    }
    if(cr < size) {  // p has a right child?
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << data[cr];
        if(data[p] < data[cr])
            std::exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
return true;
}
```

priority_queue_simple.template:

```
#include <cassert>

/**
  * Remove the largest value from this priority queue and return it.
  *
  * Precondition: priority queue is not empty.
  */
template <class T>
T priority_queue_simple<T>::remove() {
assert(size > 0);
int imax = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++ ) {
    if(data[i] > data[imax])
        imax = i;
}
T tmp = data[imax];
data[imax] = data[size-1];
size--;
return tmp;
}

/**
* Inserts the 'value' into the priority queue.
*
* Precondition: priority queue is not full
*/
template <class T>
void priority_queue_simple<T>::insert(const T& value) {
assert(size < CAPACITY);
size++;
data[size-1] = value;
}
```

priority_queue_heap.h:

```
#ifndef PRIORITY_QUEUE_HEAP_H
#define PRIORITY_QUEUE_HEAP_H

//#include "heap.h"

template <class T>
class priority_queue_heap {
priority_queue_heap();

bool is_empty() const;

bool is_full() const;

/**
 * Remove the largest value from this priority queue and return it.
 *
 * Precondition: priority queue is not empty.
 */
T remove();

/**
 * Inserts the 'value' into the priority queue.
 *
 * Precondition: priority queue is not full
 */
void insert(const T& value);

private:
heap<T> pri_que;

};

#include "priority_queue_heap.template"


#endif // PRIORITY_QUEUE_HEAP_H


template <class T>
T priority_queue_heap<T>::remove()
{
return pri_que.remove();
}
```

priority_queue_heap.template:

```
template <class T>
 T priority_queue_heap<T>::remove()
 {
  return pri_que.remove();
 }


 template <class T>
 void priority_queue_heap<T>::insert(const T& value)
 {
   pri_que.insert(value);
 }
```

priority_queue_simple.h:

```
 #ifndef PRIORITY_QUEUE_SIMPLE_H
 #define PRIORITY_QUEUE_SIMPLE_H

 /**
 * This class implements a priority queue using a very simple strategy:
 * Store the values in an array.
 * Add new values at the end.
 * When asked to remove a value, search for the largest (linear search)
 *
 */

 template <class T>
 class priority_queue_simple {
 public:
 static const int CAPACITY = 30;

 priority_queue_simple() {
    size = 0;
 }

  bool is_empty() const {
    return  size == 0;
 }

  bool is_full() const {
    return size == CAPACITY;
 }

 /**
 * Remove the largest value from this priority queue and return it.
 *
 * Precondition: priority queue is not empty.
 */
  T remove();

  /**
  * Inserts the 'value' into the priority queue.
  *
  * Precondition: priority queue is not full
  */
  void insert(const T& value);



 private:
  T data[CAPACITY];
  int size;
 };

 #include "priority_queue_simple.template"


 #endif // PRIORITY_QUEUE_SIMPLE_H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the "()" characters after enter1 at line 51 of main.cpp ...

Otherwise c++ sees that as a function, it does not call the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You have a subtle error in your heap declaration (main.cpp:57):

`priority_queue_heap<int> enter1();`

Here you are actually declaring a prototype for the `enter1` function that takes no argument and returns a `priority_queue_heap<int>`. Just remove the parentheses to actually declare a variable:

`priority_queue_heap<int> enter1;`

Answer (score 1):

```
priority_queue_heap<int> enter1();
```

Is interpreted by the compiler as a function named `enter1` that returns a `priority_queue_heap<int>` and takes no parameters.  When you use

```
cout << enter1.remove() << endl;
```

You are trying to call a member function on a name that the compiler interpreted as a function so that is why it tells you it is of non class type.  Remove the `()` from `enter1` so you have

```
priority_queue_heap<int> enter1;
```

and now `enter1` will be an object of type `priority_queue_heap<int>`